# Can I ask to check my code here? Or did I get this wrong?

Tags: discussion

If so, i will post some of my website mr2ndopinion.com. I'm looking for peer help to improve the experience of the site, i want it to be professional. Unlike my video's which are mostly made for entertaining purposes. :)

Comment: As with all Stack Exchange sites, questions about the site itself should be posted on Meta: [meta]. Also note there's guidance in the [help].

Comment: Refer to the [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to check what and how you can ask here please.

Comment: related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/327/31562 (or possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 5):

Code Review is about "doing the same thing in a better way", and while we can review the quality of your code, Code Review is not the place to ask for reviews on the *user experience* of a website.

You might however be interested in [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), although I am not sure if asking for a review of a full website is welcome there.

Comment: Well that's what i'm looking for a quality check. I teaching myself html and css with what I read on the web and that's why I posted this in the first place. So my most important question is the quality of the code. So where can I go to ask people for improving the experience? Any reference for that? Thanks a bunch

Comment: @MrsecondOpinion Also take care about linking to your website. Such might easily misconceptioned as spam at SE sites.